# How to install Ubuntu without overlapping windows boot manager

Tags: 17.10

I am wondering how can I install Ubuntu 17.10 so that the grub loader don't overlap windows boot manager by this I mean When I turn on my pc it should boot directly in windows 10 without any grub screen, I am doing this cuz I don't use Ubuntu very often and if I have to use it I can boot in by pressing f12,
I have windows already installed, I don't want to install Ubuntu then install windows to achieve it

Comment: Seems like you may want Ubuntu in a VM instead of dual-boot.

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? With UEFI, you just set UEFI to boot Windows first and press UEFI boot key like f10 or f12 to choose to boot Ubuntu. If BIOS You can still install grub and set grub's default  to boot Windows with short timeout.